# Is programming a SubCulture?

Tags: culture

I was going through this article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subculture

Which got mee thinking is programming a subculture?

After the a while I started thinking it really hard, and if you go really in depth this is a very complex and interesting question to ask.

YOu can even ask yourself if (heavy) internet (social) users are an subculture and programmers a culture within.

I think it might be an interesting discussion, hope you like it!

NOTE:

I linked the wiki article because it might be a good baseline, maybe you can base you answer  on Ken Gelder´s proposal to distinguish subcultures. But it should be based on a little bit more that intuition.

Thanks in advance!

Trufa

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, programmers are not, in themselves a subculture.  There isn't a sense of belonging shared among programmers as a group, or really any of the elements of a shared identity.  **However** -- and this is a big "however" -- a not-insignificant number of programmers are members of hacker culture.

Hackers have a shared identity, shared rituals/holiday, shared [humor](http://esr.ibiblio.org/?p=2520), a distinct shared [language](http://catb.org/jargon), they [differentiate themselves from other cultures](http://catb.org/jargon/html/crackers.html), have their [own folklore](http://catb.org/jargon/html/appendixa.html), and modes of dress, foods, habits, etc.

Hacker culture is not the same as programmer culture.  Many programmers don't grok hacker culture at all, and being a hacker isn't really defined by the activity of programming itself.  It's more about the mind set.

You may be wondering why I call hackerdom a "culture" rather than a "subculture".  Part of being a "subculture" is being somehow distinct from the "dominant culture".  However, hackers don't have a specific term for non-hackers, despite having developed an expansive distinct vocabulary.  This is because the hacker doesn't consider him/her-self not to be part of other cultures due to his/her membership in the hacker culture.  It is not only acceptable that each hacker also belong to one or more other cultures, and that [one hacker's "other" culture(s) may conflict with a fellow hacker's "other" culture(s)](http://binaryredneck.net/node/170), but it is expected, and believed by some to be the reason hacker culture exists.

[One 20th century definition of "culture"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture#American_anthropology), however, is a much better match: "the universal human capacity to classify and encode their experiences symbolically, and communicate symbolically encoded experiences socially".  Hackers share a common way of classifying and encoding experiences, a shared symbology and language, and a shared way of communicating all of these things within the hacker social group.

"Programmers" as a group doesn't seem to fit either mold to me.

--Susan

*P.S. - I registered just to answer this question, but since I am new I can't link all of my references here.  Please see my comments for URLs (if the system lets me do that).*

Links:

- Hacker humor and ritual observances (holidays): http://esr.ibiblio.org/?p=2520
- Hacker lexicon (dictionary of hacker language): http://catb.org/jargon
- How hackers differentiate themselves from other cultures/subcultures: http://catb.org/jargon/html/crackers.html
- Hacker folklore: http://catb.org/jargon/html/appendixa.html
- Hacker dress, food, habits, etc.: http://catb.org/jargon/html/appendixb.html

Comment: Hacker humor and ritual observances (holidays): http://esr.ibiblio.org/?p=2520

Comment: Hacker lexicon (dictionary of hacker language): http://www.catb.org/jargon/

Comment: How hackers differentiate themselves from other cultures/subcultures: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/crackers.html

Comment: Hacker folklore: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/appendixa.html

Comment: Hacker dress, food, habits, etc.: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/appendixb.html

Comment: Welcome to to the site. Excellent answer, really. Congratulations! Hang around!

Comment: My argument on the utility of hacker culture, especially with regard to the fact that hackers all belong to "other" cultures, some of which are mutually antagonistic: http://binaryredneck.net/node/170

Comment: Wikipedia entry on "culture", specifically the section from which I quoted the definition of "culture" above: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture#American_anthropology

Comment: Hedge - I've edited your answer to include your links, and (hopefully) linkified the appropriate words too.

Answer (score 6):

No.  Programmers are no more a subculture than engineers, doctors, or lawyers.  If professions were actually subcultures then the word wouldn't mean very much.

Let's look at the 6 criteria on the Wikipedia page:

*1. through their often negative relations to work (as 'idle', 'parasitic', at play or at leisure, etc.);*

This is obviously not the case.  Most decent programmers work reasonably hard and enjoy it to some extent.

*2. through their negative or ambivalent relation to class (since subcultures are not 'class-conscious' and don't conform to traditional class definitions);*

Most programmers are middle-class, so this doesn't even really apply.

*3. through their association with territory (the 'street', the 'hood, the club, etc.), rather than property;*

Unless the internet counts as territory, I'd have to say no to this as well.

*4. through their movement out of the home and into non-domestic forms of belonging (i.e. social groups other than the family);*

A lot of programmers are on the anti-social side but again, and even the internet doesn't really apply here because everybody uses social networks now.

*5. through their stylistic ties to excess and exaggeration (with some exceptions);*

Most definitely not the case with programmers.

*6. through their refusal of the banalities of ordinary life and massification.*

Pretty much every programmer I know enjoys the casual comforts of beer, pizza, and computer games.

Verdict:  **No**, programming isn't a subculture.  It's a career.  What you do for a living has very little to do with how your philosophy on society.

Comment: I like you answer but i´m going answer toy your answer with a different perspective.

Comment: Those items were listed in the wikipedia article as defining characteristics of *countercultures*, not subcultures in general.

Comment: @HedgeMage: You're incorrect.  Read it again, particularly the very last sentence before the list.

Comment: Aaronaught, my apologies you are correct: I seem to have skimmed past a sentence.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's almost 11pm on Friday. An I'm answering your question...

I think it's a subculture with a *lot* of members. Similar to the hippy/counter-culture movement in the late 60's.

Comment: good comparison!! sometimes this SE is addictive!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be. I've been involved in the demo scene in early 90s, building a diskmag called Imphobia talking about demos parties. The demo scene is defined like this:

> The demoscene is a computer art subculture that specializes in producing demos, which are non-interactive audio-visual presentations that run in real-time on a computer. The main goal of a demo is to show off programming, artistic, and musical skills.

**So yes I think programming is a subculture**

Comment: What do you think about HedgeMedge answer that (I think) was basically saying that programming was too broad and too different peoples to be a subculture?

Comment: I did not write the quote above, however I actively participated to the demo scene, and I can confirm it is a cultural phenomenom

Comment: Well demoscene is clearly a subculture, but that doesn't make programming in general a [sub]culture - in the same way hip-hop being a subculture doesn't make music in general a [sub]culture.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe. I think there is programming culture such as famous programming figures. Not all programmers belong to it. It is also closely related to computer nerd culture.